# How to prevent Deadlock exception in SELECT FOR UPDATE after the update?

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, innodb, pessimistic-locking

I have an `account` table with 1 row.
I have 2 threads which do the next:

1st thread:

```
begin transaction;
select * from account where balance=0 for update;
UPDATE account SET balance = 10 WHERE balance=0;
// waiting here for several seconds
commit transaction;
```

2nd thread:

```
begin transaction;
select * from account where balance=0 for update;
commit transaction;
```

The flow is the next:
1) 1st thread starts and proceeds up to the `waiting here for several seconds` line.
2) 2nd thread starts and is blocked (logically because the 1st thread has not released pessimistic locks yet).
3) 1st thread successfully commits a transaction.
4) 2nd thread gets an error: `ERROR 1213 (40001): Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction`

Why Deadlock exception is getting in such scenario, if there is no deadlocks? I tried this scenario with all 4 transaction isolation levels and with all isolation levels the same error is acquired.

Comment: Use the innodb status monitor to find out what exactly causes the deadlock.

Comment: @Shadow thank you. I will try to monitor it and then I will update the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was my mistake. So the above code actually should work.
My problem was that I used `lock in share mode` in the first thread and in the second I used `for update`. I thought that they are the same, but actually they are not. When I changed the first thread to use `for update` also, they started to work correctly.

Thanks to [Shadow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5389997) who gave a tip to use innodb status monitor to check deadlock transactions information (`SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS;`).